# pie chart based on checkbox array

Tags: php, mysqli, fusioncharts

Hi i have a project where am making pie chart in my dashboard.the problem am facing is that i have one column that accepts multiple checkbox value.

I have attached an image on how it appears [Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S9Rq.jpg)
So i was asking if somebody would help me so the values can be presented individually not as group.`
This is my source code

```
include("fusioncharts.php");
$hostdb = "localhost";  // MySQl host
$userdb = "root";  // MySQL username
$passdb = "";  // MySQL password
$namedb = "school";  // MySQL database name

$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);
if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
    exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
}

$strQuery = "SELECT combination, COUNT(combination) FROM schools GROUP BY  combination order by COUNT(combination)";
$result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

if ($result) {
    $arrData = array(
        "chart" => array(
            "caption" => "Numbers of Schools Based on Different Combination",
            "theme" => "fusion",
            "caption" => "",
            "showPercentInTooltip" => "0",
            "enableMultiSlicing" =>"1",
        )
    );
    $data = array();
    $arrData["data"] = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" =>$row["combination"] ,
                "value" =>  $row["COUNT(combination)"]
            )
        );
    }

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

    $columnChart = new FusionCharts("pie3D", "myFirstChart" , 900, 500, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);
    $columnChart->render();
    $dbhandle->close();
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid mixing procedural and object-oriented `mysqli` syntax.

Comment: _“i have one column that accepts multiple checkbox value”_ - explain what that actually _means_. What data do you get, and how do you want to display it?

Comment: what i mean is that the column receives more than one checkbox posted from the form.so they are stored as an array.so in pie chart it is presented as single value like the way it shows in the image i linked

Comment: Please add new question details to your question as an edit (then delete your comment) -- this ensures that the full "story" is all in one place.

Comment: i dont undestand

Comment: Your question is Unclear and may be closed.  Please edit your question to describe what the input (array) data might be and how that will impact the code logic.  From some sample input data, what will be your expected result?